# Read JavaScript Object needs JSON conversion

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a javascript object .

```
var homeObject=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BuildingObject));
var flatNumber=homeObject.flatNo;
```

So, Is there any way to get **flatNo** property directly without JSON conversion.

Also, Adding a further note:

`BuildingObject.flatNo` returns undefined if accessed directly, without JSON conversion

JSON output of BuildingObject is listed below

```
{

    "flatNo": "34",
    "objectId": "4oRaVl96ZQ",
    "createdAt": "2013-03-01T17:35:27.724Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-03-01T17:40:45.804Z"
}
```

Still surprised! It prints out `BuildingObject.createdAt` and `BuildingObject.updatedAt` .
Issue is with String Objects "flatNo" and "objectId"

Comment: `BuildingObject.flatNo` doesn't work?

Comment: I suggest you use Firebug's console (or your browser's equivalent) to inspect your variable with `console.log(BuildingObject)`.

Comment: I printed out the object Type and is "Object"

Comment: Then try `console.log()` in a better browser. If I recall correctly, Chrome, Firefox and Opera display full info about objects.

Comment: Show how `BuildingObject` looks like

Comment: Show us what `BuildingObject` is, please. Just log the result of the JSON stringification

Comment: if BuildingObject is a javascript Object, then there is no need whatsoever to Stringify and the parse it, as @zzzzBov stated, by doing a call to BuildingObject.flatNo should do the trick, try it in a console.log call: `console.log(BuildingObject.flatNo)`

Comment: Is there any chance that you inspect the complete original `BuildingObject` variable with `console.log()` as you've been suggested?

Comment: No dear, I don't think so. I have a standalone javascript, whose execution is managed by Parse.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem likely stems from the fact that JSON.stringify() will try to call toJSON() on the object first, so it's very possible that toJSON() is adding properties that aren't keys of the original object. e.g.

```
var test = {
    toJSON: function () {
        return {
            foo: "bar"
        };
    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
// outputs: {"foo":"bar"} 

console.log(test.foo);
// outputs: undefined

console.log(test.toJSON().foo);
// outputs: bar
```

So in your case you could:

a) Check if your BuildingObject has some kind of accessor function for flatNo, e.g. BuildingObject.get('flatNo')

or

b) Use BuildingObject.toJSON().flatNo

Comment: Oh you got it right. I logged out the entire Object. It print outs a HashMap, which has toJSON(). Now this toJSON() creates a Hash map response. Hence I am able to read it through test.toJSON().foo..Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `BuildingObject` is an object that contains a property called `flatNo`, the property can be read with the standard JavaScript syntax:

- `BuildingObject.flatNo`
- `BuildingObject["flatNo"]`

Test code:

```
var BuildingObject = {
    flatNo: 314
};
console.log(BuildingObject.flatNo, BuildingObject["flatNo"]);
```

... prints, as expected:

> 314 314

There's absolutely no need to use JSON when dealing with JavaScript objects. Despite common believe, JSON is nothing but a plain text data format that's inspired by JavaScript syntax. JSON is not JavaScript and there's no thing as "JSON object" (a term you can read in endless questions on StackOverflow referring to JavaScript objects) because if it's JSON it's a string.

If `BuildingObject.flatNo` returns undefined for you, then `BuildingObject` does not contain what you think it does or your test has a flaw somewhere.